# How can I fix my C++ code ? (no match for operators)

Tags: c++, operators

How can I fix my C++ code ? (no match for operators)
I got an error : no match for "operators-". What can be the problem and how can I solve it?
Can anybody help me to fix it ?

> error: no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'std::set::iterator' {aka 'std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator'} and 'std::set::iterator' {aka 'std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator'})|

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int O;
    int N;
    int M;

    cin >> O >> N >> M;

    int tanarsorszama[O];
    int tantargysorszama[O];
    int nap [O];
    int ora [O];

    for(int i=0; i<O; i++)
    {
        cin >> tanarsorszama[i] >> tantargysorszama[i] >> nap[i] >> ora[i];
    }

    int dblyukas[N]={0};
    set<int>orai; 

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(int k=1; k<6; k++)
        {
           orai.clear();  

            for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
            {
                if(tanarsorszama[i]!=0 && ora!=0 && nap[k]!=0)
                {
                    orai.insert(ora[j]);   
                }
            }
            if (orai.size() > 1) 
            {
              dblyukas[i] += orai.end() - orai.begin() +1 - orai.size();  // There is the error
            }
         }
     }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the marked line?  `std::set` is an RBTree, so subtracting iterators doesn't really make sense with that unlike like if you used an vector.

Comment: FYI, the capacity of arrays needs to be specified at runtime.  You have Variable Length Arrays (VLAs), which are not standard C++.  See also `std::vector`.

Comment: Please avoid using 1 letter variable names for anything other than an index of a loop. This is considered a bad practice as it make code harder to read.

Comment: Prefer to not use `O` as a variable name, as it is often confused with the number zero, `'0'`.

Comment: Your complex equation simplifies to `orai.end() - orai.begin() +1 - orai.size() == orai.size() + 1 - orai.size() == 1`, so perhaps you do not need to do any iterator arithmetics at all?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen beat me by a few seconds... your complex and uncompilable expression just means `1`.  We can not "fix your code" without knowing what your code was attempting to do.

Comment: I would like to add the value that I get from the withdrawals of my set, which will be a number.

Comment: `int tanarsorszama[O];` is not allowed in Standard C++. The dimension of C-style arrays must be a compile-time constant expression

Comment: @batat So you want to access the first and last element of the set and not use iterator arithmetic?

Comment: Yes . Is this possible?

Comment: Yes.  `*begin(orai)` is the first element.  `*prev(end(orai))` is the last.  The set must not be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::set` doesn't have random-access iterators. That is why you are getting the error.

To access the first and last elements of a set, use `orai.begin()` and `std::prev(orai.end())`. These return iterators, which will have to be de-referenced with operator*. So, correcting what I think you are intending to do, leads to the following:

```
            if (orai.size() > 1) 
            {
              dblyukas[i] += *std::prev(orai.end()) - *orai.begin() +1 - orai.size();  // There is the error
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!